# Not able to log in

Tags: 10.10, gdm, login

When I boot my computer, I get the regular option to start Ubuntu in the boot menu. After I log in with the correct password, it logs me back out again.

I ran the recovery option, but it's still the same. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you just installed Ubuntu or did you upgrade it? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Do you have Skype installed?

Answer (score 2):

Switch to a virtual terminal: CTRL-ALT-F1, login with your user.
Add a new user admin user with the following commands:

```
sudo adduser tmpadmin
sudo usermod -G admin tmpadmin
```

Now switch back to GDM, CTRL-ALT-F8, try to login with the new user.
If it works then there is an issue with the startup apps or configuration specific to the affected user.
With tmpadmin you should be able to browse to the other users home dir, check the file 
.xsession-errors for errors that might be related to issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also was returned to login screen, but for me it was xorg configuration issue.
Here is the solution:

I was able to run Xfce manager. Then i run from terminal or alt+f2:

```
nvidia-settings
```

go to 'X Server Display Configuration', click 'Reset' button, then 'Save to X Configuration file'
In new window uncheck 'merge..' option and click 'save' button.